# Query posts only with featured image

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

I want to query 6 posts, but only those which have a featured image attached. I am using `meta_key` method for this with `WP_Query` as such:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
    'post_count' => 6 );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Followed by

```
<?php while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This doesn't seem to work. The query is returning more than 6 posts and also those which don't have a featured image. Any ideas what I've got wrong here?

@chip: `var_dump($query);` gives a large result so I have posted it in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KNw9yuKb)

Comment: The code snippet worked for me as expected. Maybe the error is in another part of the code.

Comment: What do you get from `var_dump( $query )`?

Comment: As a extra thing I thought of - the posts were imported to my local server from a live site using wordpress exporter/importer. The original posts all had featured images which were obviously lost in the import process. Could that mean that although the featured images were removed the meta keys still remained causing the query to mess up?

Comment: When you ran the import, did you check the box to download and attach all attachments/media? If you did not then your featured images will not work. The posts will have a featured image, but it will be referencing an attachment that does not exist, and so will never be displayed

Comment: Yes, I checked the box when importing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running the importer, you must check the checkbox to download and import all media/attachments, and the original server must be reachable from the server conducting the import.

If you fail to do this, the posts will have no valid featured image, and fail to show in your loop, and any attempt to call `the_post_thumbnail` will fail giving the impression they have no featured image.

To fix this, delete your posts, and re-import using the correct settings, making sure the old server is still accessible at its original URL.

Also to demonstrate the point, you made no attempt to actually check the posts, always check e.g.:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { // you never checked to see if no posts were found
    while($query->have_posts()) { // alt style syntax doesn't work with most IDEs
        // individual statement should be on individual line
        $query->the_post();

        // you only need open/close tags here, not every line, save yourself some time typing
        ?><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><?php 

        // only print out the thumbnail if it actually has one
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            echo '<p>post says it has a featured image</p>'; // double checking
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
        } else {
            echo '<p>this post does not have a featured image</p>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>no posts found</p>';
}
```

If you have not checked the checkbox, you will get images saying they have a featured image, but no image is shown

Comment: I suspect this is the reason the answer I provided isn't working as expected.  the [WordPress Suicide](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/suicide/) plugin is pretty helpful for deleting all content.

Comment: I definitely did check that box. However in my experience it has never worked for me. All the images were linked back to the external site. I used the Import External Images(http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-external-images/) plugin to store the images locally and attach.

Comment: I've had the same thought, I definitely checked the box, why does it not work still? I've had it from clients, and it's so easy to get wrong, so delete your posts, re-import and make sure it's checked, and if it **still** doesn't work then you can rule it out. Otherwise there's a Neil DeGrasse Tyson talk about how pathetically weak human memory is. Right now I could ask you to uncheck the second tickbox and you'd probably remember seeing that too ( but there isn't one )

Comment: and in the meantime, wrap `the_post_thumbnail` with a `has_thumbnail` call and add an else case so that you definitely unambiguously know that the post doesn't have a featured image

Comment: Also make sure your server is able to reach the remote server. If your server is unable to grab remote requests, it will be unable to import. You may well need to delete the media attachments already grabbed

Comment: @Tom thanks for your comments. I know you say it is easy to forget doing something but I KNOW I did check the box. The thing is, it has very frequently not worked for me; I check the box but none of the images import and I'm left with all the posts having externally linked images in them. My server is a simple Xampp setup running on MacOS which does have remote access. My feeling is that it's a combination of the checkbox failing and the plugin I used to grab all the images  failing to "feature" the images properly. I will try your suggestions this evening and report back

Comment: XAMPP is a windows only tool? Rather than argue about what you think you know and your feelings, demonstrate it via the debug code and post useful, helpful, unambiguous, hard data. Capital letters will not help you. I've been able to recreate this issue many times locally and on client servers by checking or not checking, and have made the mistake myself, and it is currently the most accurate theory given the information provided. If you disagree then provide new information so that we may arrive at a better theory

Comment: No Xampp works well on Mac too! Unfortunately there is no concrete evidence that I did or didn't click the checkbox but that's kinda irrelevant. The problem is because the media import failed - the post thinks it has a featured image as the meta tag is there but there is no actual image. Adding a new featured image and removing it prevents the post from coming up showing the query works, which is what I wanted to know. thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 31):

As of WordPress 3.5, the [Meta Query Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) support `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` as compare operators.  In the case where you are using these, you can omit the `value` part of the meta query.  Try the following arguments for your query:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'  => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
         'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
         'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I now get the 6 posts but still get posts without thumbnails.

Comment: I tested this and it worked for me.  But I did notice that it will return entities that have the meta set, but for some reason that attachment ID isn't correct.  So double check that your posts have the featured images set.  Otherwise, I don't know what else the problem could be.

Comment: harryg, can you confirm you're using v3.5 or later?

Comment: Yes I am running the latest version of WordPress - freshly installed on my local dev server as a network (multisite) setup.

Comment: Just some additional information: There is a unresolved bug, see [trac ticket 23268](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23268), which makes it necessary to use a value if `NOT EXISTS` is used.