# Add "Category" to Mysql Query

Tags: wp-query, mysql

i need your help :)

I've made this custom Mysql query on WordPress:

```
    $querystr = "
   SELECT  DISTINCT meta_value  FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN(     
   SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta.post_id
   FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
   WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
   AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'color' 
   AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = 'red' 
   AND wposts.post_type = 'post' ) AND meta_key ='size' 
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 4
   ";
```

How can i ADD in the query search for "Category name" or "Category ID" ?

Cheers ;)

Comment: Can't see any reason why this wouldn't be doable with [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: Hi Ialocin, beacause i need ONLY one results
by color red but different sizes ! How can i do it with WP Query ?

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not missing something, the below should work for you. It is pretty much straight from the [Codex: WP_Query - Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). Do it like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'color',
            'value' => 'red',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'size',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Additional resources on here:

- [Meta_query compare operator explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/70870/22534)
- [Query posts only with featured image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89204/22534)
- there are more, just use the [search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=meta_query)

Comment: YES, works very FINE ;)

Comment: Good :) Remember using WordPress' build-in functionality is almost always preferable, of course sometimes you reach the boundaries of that, then you have to switch to a (more) custom solution. @CaponiElia Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

To ADD in the query search for "Category name" or "Category ID"   you have to apply inner join with ( wp_term_relationships ).

Pls try this

$category_id is your category id

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'color',
            'value' => 'red',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'size',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $category_id,
                    'operator'  => 'IN'
                )),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

Comment: Please extend your answer with a proper explanation.

Comment: I've try but with no results...TBI can u give an example with my code ? :)

Comment: Please specify your post type , category name and any other information that could help to solve this.